# 'setState' not working in navigated page if custom color is used

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, navigation, setstate

For some reason, whenever I navigate to another route using the way described in flutter's documentation i.e https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics, and if I have used custom color in the following way:


`color: Color(0xff0e0f26),`

in that route, the `setState` method doesn't work in it. However, if I use color in the following way: 
`color: Colors.blue,` 
the `setState` method works. I have no idea what is causing this. I want to use a color value that is not present amongst the colors that flutter provides. How do I fix this? The full code along with explanation (using comments) is here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'test',
      theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: homepage(),
    );
  }
}

class homepage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _homepageState createState() => _homepageState();
}

class _homepageState extends State<homepage>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Color(0xff0e0f26),
        child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
      );
     },
    ),
   )
  );
 }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute>{
  bool test = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Color(0xff0e0f26), //Here, if I use 'color: Colors.blue', setState works.
        child:Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){ //When the button is pressed, setState is triggered.
                setState((){ //This should theoretically rebuild the widget with 'test' becoming true
                             //, thus showing the text widget below in the screen, but it doesn't.
                  test = true;
                });
              },
            ),
            test ? Text("HELLO"):SizedBox(), //I want 'test' to become true, thus making the text
                                             //widget come on screen.
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It shows the `Text` widget. To make sure, set the `Text`'s color to a lighter color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text ist just too dark.
If you use

```
test ? Text("HELLO", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white30),):SizedBox(),
```

it should work. This just makes your text lighter. You should use ElevatedButton instead of RaisedButton, since RaisedButton is deprecated and could cause problems as well.